# Extract specific data from sheet and create attachment for email

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to isolate the data that is cross referenced between my "Email Format" sheet and my "Data" sheet, and attach only the relevant data for each specific recipient and send it as individual attachments.

Let's say I have two sheets.

1. Email Format:

```
 key    recipients
1388633 ci6@gmail.com
1386192 cp8@gmail.com
1384662 pl3@gmail.com
1387028 wd9@gmail.com
```

2. Data:

```
Key     Frequency   Volatility
1388633    1.4      0.7
1388633    2        0.4
1388633    3.7      0.1
1387028    2.3      6
1387028    3.45     5.7
1386192    3.89     7.26
1386192    4.33     8.82
```

How can I create emails with a specific Excel attachment for each recipient based on common key for 1388633, 1387028 and 1386192 and then send to their respective email addresses?

For instance, based on the common key 1388633 in "Email Format" and "Data":
To: ci6@gmail.com (which is the email address for key 1388633 )
Attachment: An excel file that only contains

```
Key     Frequency   Volatility
1388633    1.4      0.7
1388633    2        0.4
1388633    3.7      0.1
```

The same for the others.

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wB As Workbook: Set wB = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsD As Worksheet: Set wsD = wB.Worksheets("Data")
Dim wsE As Worksheet: Set wsE = wB.Worksheets("Email Format")
Dim LastRowsData As Integer
Dim LastRowEmail As Integer
Dim OA As Outlook.Application: Set OA = New Outlook.Application
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem: Set msg = OA.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Dim Recipient As String

Recipient = Worksheets("Email Format").Range("A2")
LastRowsData = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
LastRowEmail = Worksheets("Email Format").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRowsData
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(wsD.Range("H" & i).Value, _
        wsD.Range("A1:A" & LastRowsData), 0)) Then
        LastRowEmail = LastRowEmail + 1
        wsE.Range("A" & LastRowEmail).Value = wsD.Range("G" & i).Value
    End If
Next i
    
For i = 2 To LastRowEmail

    Set msg = OA.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With msg
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = wsE.Range("D" & i).Value
        .To = wsE.Range("A" & i).Value
        .Subject = wsE.Range("C" & i).Value
        .Display
    End With

Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What are "specific attachments(excel)"?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz I've made an Edit which specifies what I meant. Is quite difficult to explain but I think is clear now :)

Comment: I suggest you use a filter on the table; copy the visible rows to a new Excel sheet; and send that sheet as an attachment for the corresponding email.

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld so there is no way you see to express it in code?

Comment: What makes you think that?  What did I write that gave you a problem doing in code? What was the problem?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz Thank you! I will check if the code and relay back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. Read the comments. Adjust it to fit your needs.

Run it by stepping into the code pressing `F8`

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PrepareEmails()

    ' Declare general variables
    Dim emailSheetName As String
    Dim dataSheetName As String
    
    
    ' Set values to fit your needs
    emailSheetName = "Email Format"
    dataSheetName = "Data"
    
    ' Declare and initiate eMail sheet
    Dim eMailSheet As Worksheet
    Set eMailSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(emailSheetName)
    
    ' Declare and initiate eMail sheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dataSheetName)
    
    
    ' Get last row in each sheet
    Dim emailLastRow As Long
    Dim dataLastRow As Long
    
    emailLastRow = eMailSheet.Cells(eMailSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    dataLastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    ' Get the range of data in each sheet
    Dim emailRange As Range
    Dim dataRange As Range
    
    Set emailRange = eMailSheet.Range("A2:B" & emailLastRow) ' Set the first row to what you need
    Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range("A1:C" & dataLastRow) ' Set the first row to what you need (include headers)
    
    ' Clear previous filters
    On Error Resume Next
    dataRange.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Loop through emails
    Dim emailRow As Range
    Dim relatedData As Range
    For Each emailRow In emailRange.Rows
        
        ' Filter data based on key
        dataRange.AutoFilter 1, emailRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
        
        ' Set range to visible cells
        Set relatedData = dataRange.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
        
        ' If there are visible cells, do something
        If Not relatedData Is Nothing Then
                    
            ' Prepare attachment
            Dim filePath As String
            Dim key As String
            Dim recipient As String
            Dim emailSubject As String
            Dim body As String
            
            
            key = emailRow.Cells(1, 1).Value ' 1= column A
            recipient = emailRow.Cells(1, 2).Value  ' 1= column B
            emailSubject = "Subject" ' you can use what is in column C changing the string to something like emailRow.Cells(1, 3).Value
            body = "Hi, attached file!" ' Change this to whatever html body you like (I'd set it to a cell reference so I'd change it easily)
            
            filePath = "C:\Temp\" & key & ".xlsx" ' Make sure C:\Temp or whatever path you specify exists
            
            prepareAttachment filePath, relatedData
            
            sendEmail key, recipient, emailSubject, body, filePath
        
        End If
    
    Next emailRow

    
End Sub

Private Sub prepareAttachment(ByVal filePath As String, ByVal relatedData As Range)
    
    ' Copy the range to new sheet in new file
    Dim newFile As Workbook
    Set newFile = Workbooks.Add
    relatedData.Copy newFile.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
    
    ' Save the file and overwrite if exists
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newFile.SaveAs filePath
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    newFile.Close
    
End Sub
 
Private Sub sendEmail(ByVal key As String, ByVal recipient As String, ByVal emailSubject As String, ByVal body As String, ByVal attachmentPath As String)

    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim message As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set message = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    recipient = recipient
    
    With message
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
        .HTMLBody = body
        .To = recipient
        .subject = emailSubject
        .Display
        .Attachments.Add attachmentPath
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works.